# Lost solving a trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac { 2+\tan^2x }{  \sec^2x} -1$$

Steps I took:

$$\begin{align}
\frac { 2+\tan^2x }{  \sec^2x} -1
&=\frac { 2+\frac { \sin^{ 2 }x }{ \cos^{ 2 }x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \cos^2x }  } -1\\
&=\frac { 2\cos^{ 2 }x+\sin^{ 2 }x }{ \cos^{ 2 }x } \cdot \frac { \cos^{ 2 }x }{ 1 } -1\\
&=\frac { (2\cos^{ 2 }x+\sin^{ 2 }x)\cos^{ 2 }x }{ \cos^{ 2 }x } -1\\
&=2\cos^{ 2 }x+\sin^{ 2 }x-1\\
\end{align}$$

Now I have no idea where to go from here.. Please guide me in the right direction

Comment: $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$

Comment: $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$. Yes this is an identity. The ans =$cos^2x$

Comment: @Integrator "What's in a name ..." ~ **Shakespeare**. Its not a typo. the spelling is archaic. fine?

Comment: hint: $2\cos^2 x = \cos^2 x+\cos^2 x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying  the numerator & the denominator by $\cos^2x,$

$$\frac{2+\tan^2x}{\sec^2x}-1=2\cos^2x+\sin^2x-1$$

$$=2\cos^2x-(1-\sin^2x)=\cos^2x$$

Comment: Is $2cos^{ 2 }x=cos^2x+cos^2x$ ??

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Any doubt? $a^2+a^2=?$

Comment: Oh my god. You people type faster than speed of light. @Cherry_Developer Of course! +1 Anyway :(

Comment: $2a^2$
So then $2cos^2x+sin^2x-1$ is the same as $cos^2x +cos^{ 2 }x+sin^{ 2 }x-1$ and that just simplified to $cos^{ 2 }x$ ??

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{2+\tan^2 x}{\sec^2 x} - 1= \frac{1 + 1 +\tan^2 x}{\sec^2 x} - 1 = \frac{1 + \sec^2 x}{\sec^2 x} - 1.
$$

thus you end up getting
$$
\frac{1}{\sec^2 x} + 1 - 1 = \cos^2 x
$$
dunno how this helps you in the long run..